# Go to internet with another WAN IP

Tags: networking, router, internet, routing

I have router A
External: 10.10.10.10/30
Internal: 192.168.10.10/24

Router B
External: 10.10.10.254/30
Internal: 192.168.11.10/24

How to make router B to go to the internet via router A external IP? They re connected to switch. They are comminicating with each other (internal/external). Do I have to configure NAT or smth?

Comment: You could try pinging them to see if they can reach eachother. Also you could download cisco packet tracer to try and replicate your network situation and make things easier :)

Comment: They can. I just want to know what should i do to go to the internet with another external ip. If you can help - thanks

Comment: You need to setup default route on `10.10.10.254/30` that point to `10.10.10.10/30`

Comment: @alex I tries to do it, but the IP stays the same

Comment: Does router B needs to be on the same LAN as router A for any reason? if not, why not just connect router B's WAN port to router A's LAN? Why connect router B to the 10.10.10.0/30 network?

Comment: Then change on router B WAN settings to  10.10.10.10/30 network. CIDR /30 means you have 2 available IP `10.10.10.9` and `10.10.10.10`, use one for A and another for B

Answer (score 0):

As I now sort of understand what you mean. You canno't have router A in house A and Router B in house B and then use Router B as a switch to access Router A in house A. You can however setup a VPN on a computer in house A and then access that VPN from house B. This way it will show your IP as Router A while you are connecting to the VPN from Router B.

Lets say behind router B is an FTP sever on port 21. If you want to connect to that FTP server trough router A you would need to type in Explorer: ftp://externalIP. Ofcourse you would also need to portforward port 21 on router A to go to the FTP service.

Comment: So I can reach it, but how to make that when i connect to router b whatnyip.org shows router a external ip?

Comment: @Tomas yes whatsmyip.org shows your routers external ip

Comment: So, my question is how to make router b go to internet through router a? I mean if I connect to router b i want to have router a external ip

Comment: So basically your question is how to use router B as a switch.

Comment: No . I want to have both external IPs.  But want to connect to another IP to internet

Comment: What does it mean to have an external IP but not to use it to reach the Internet? It's very hard to understand what you're trying to do and why you've set things up the way you have.

Comment: I already did IP tunnel 10.10.10.1 and 10.10.10.2, but it stills doesnt show that ip 